# CodedUI and Setup Installer Not Working

Tags: c#, visual-studio, installation, coded-ui-tests

I used the CodedUI to record the installation of a product, and tried to replay the recording in visual studio. I'm getting some curious issues and I'm not sure how to work around these.

```
    Message: Test method CodedUITestProject5.CodedUITest1.CodedUITestMethod1 threw exception: 
Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.FailedToLaunchApplicationException: "The application cannot be started because it cannot be found in the specified location, or the user does not have sufficient permissions to start the application." File: C:\Users\Sakamoto\AppData\Local\Temp\{CF4F5CDB-4597-4C70-BBFD-2687BB031067}\.cr\Setup.exe. Alternative file name: %TMP%\{CF4F5CDB-4597-4C70-BBFD-2687BB031067}\.cr\Setup.exe
```

The funny thing is the setup file is located on my desktop, and that's where the recording launched it from. Looking in UIMap.Designer.cs, it has to correct path listed in the recorded method right under the Variable Declarations section.

I am also running Visual Studio 2017 as Administrator.

Changing the UIMap.Designer.cs file so that all paths point to the file on the desktop, I get the following error:

```
    Message: Test method CodedUITestProject5.CodedUITest1.CodedUITestMethod1 threw exception: 
Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.FailedToLaunchApplicationException: "The application cannot be started. This could be due to one of the following reasons:
1) Another instance of the application is already running and only one instance can be running at a time.
2) The application started another process and has now stopped. You may need to launch the process directly.
3) You do not have sufficient privileges for this application." File: C:\Users\Sakamoto\Desktop\Setup.exe.
```

Can someone help me get an automated run of the setup process going?